# sign apk with system certificate

Tags: java, android, events, keystore, keytool

Hi i am writing a program which uses event injection.so in order to get system privileges i have to sign the apk with the certificate of the system. I tried as mentioned in this link
http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/apk-with-system-privileges/
https://github.com/getfatday/keytool-importkeypair

but when i tried i got the following error

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -importkeypair -k ~/C:\Users\name\.androiddebug.keystore -p android -pk8 platform.pk8 -cert platform.x509.
pem -alias platform
Illegal option:  -importkeypair
Key and Certificate Management Tool

Commands:

 -certreq            Generates a certificate request
 -changealias        Changes an entry's alias
 -delete             Deletes an entry
 -exportcert         Exports certificate
 -genkeypair         Generates a key pair
 -genseckey          Generates a secret key
 -gencert            Generates certificate from a certificate request
 -importcert         Imports a certificate or a certificate chain
 -importkeystore     Imports one or all entries from another keystore
 -keypasswd          Changes the key password of an entry
 -list               Lists entries in a keystore
 -printcert          Prints the content of a certificate
 -printcertreq       Prints the content of a certificate request
 -printcrl           Prints the content of a CRL file
 -storepasswd        Changes the store password of a keystore

Use "keytool -command_name -help" for usage of command_name
```

Comment: Hi,pls share if you found your soln.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>` and then

try this

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\[your_user_name]\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is of keytool-importkeypair, not keytool
You will need to add keytool-importkeypair to your path somehow

Answer (score 0):

keytool-importkeypair is a single command without space. To make this work:

1) Download the keytool-importkeypair from following location and save it to the same folder where platform certs are present

https://github.com/getfatday/keytool-importkeypair

2) Once the file is there, you can simply use it by typing

$./keytool-importkeypair "rest of the command"